# Why access using IE browser and access using Windows explorer of INetCache folder shows different folder structure on WIN8.1-IE11?

Tags: ruby, windows, caching, internet-explorer-11, directory

When I access C:\Users\shan\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache using Windows explorer, it shows following folder structure:
[image]

But when I access the same using IE11 browser, Tools->Internet Options->General->Browsing history-> Settings(click)->View files(click), I get different folder structure as follows:

[image]
  Why folder structure  differing in above 2 cases, even though both are referring to the same physical location on Windows 8.1, IE11 Browser ?

I need to write a script which clears this INetCache folder contents(Cache). But not able to get the exact content of this folder. Because it always refers to Folder which contains Low(folder), Virtualized(folder) and counters.dat(file). In my script I want to refer the folder which contains favicon.ico files.

The same behavior is observed on IE10-win7 and IE11-win7 as well, while referencing Temporary Internet Files.

Answer (score 0):

There is an internal api in the IE libraries that controls clearing of the 'Internet Cache'....
there are two... one for 'normal' integrity processes (64 bit tab processes and ActiveX (flash)), another for low integrity processes (32 bit tab processes and ActiveX (flash))

Use GPO (Start>Run>gpedit.msc) to configure user profiles on a domain network to empty the TIF(s) on exit from the browser.

For computers on a public access network (library workstations), you can default to inPrivate Mode from a desktop or Taskbar link

iexplore.exe -private

which does not retain any personally identifiable data of the user in history, or cookies or flash cookies.....

questions about GPO management of IE should be posted to the TechNet support forum for IE.
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/home?forum=ieitprocurrentver

Comment: Here the problem is how to refer the INetCache folder  which contains .ico files. Whenever I try to refer this folder in any programming code, always it uses folder which contains Low(folder), Virtualized(folder) and counters.dat(file). Even dir command also shows the same content. How to access these .ico files programatically?